# "Any"; universal or existential quantifier?

Tags: logic, quantifiers, predicate-logic

> For any integers $m$ and $n$, if $7m+5n=147$, then $m$ is odd or $n$ is odd.

$$Q(m,n) \equiv 7m+5n=147$$

$$∀m∀n: Q(m,n) → \bigl(m \not\equiv 0 \!\!\pmod 2 \lor n \not\equiv 0 \!\! \pmod 2\bigr)$$

Am I right in assuming $\forall$ means "any" in this case? It doesn't seem to make sense to me ($\exists$ to me means "at least one, many, one, all but one, etc; anything less than all but more than none"), but Wikipedia states that $\forall$ can also mean "for any".

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Normally mod is done $m\not\equiv 0\mod 2$.

Comment: $\forall$ means "for all" or "every".  $\exists$ means "exists" and could include any possibility except "does not exist".  In particular, $\exists$ includes "all".

Comment: "Any" can mean "for all" or "there exists" depending on the sentence. It takes some experience to tell, in a particular sentence, which meaning is intended. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509520/the-use-of-any-as-opposed-to-every/509828#509828

Comment: Also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402020/whats-the-difference-between-any-all-and-some/402073#402073

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\forall m$ is usually read *for all m* or *for each m*; *for any m* is a possible paraphrase in some contexts. $\forall x\big(\varphi(x)\big)$ means that for all possible values of $x$ in the domain of discourse, the statement $\varphi(x)$ about $x$ is true. If you think of $\varphi(x)$ as saying that $x$ has some particular property, then $\forall x\big(\varphi(x)\big)$ says that every element in the domain of discourse has that property.

Your understanding of $\exists$ isn’t quite correct, however; $\exists m\big(\varphi(m)\big)$ means precisely that there is at least one thing in the domain of discourse that has the property in question. It does **not** exclude the possibility that every element of the domain of discourse has it. For example, if we’re talking about integers, $$\exists n(n\text{ is even }\lor n\text{ is odd}\}$$ is a true statement, even though $$\forall n(n\text{ is even }\lor n\text{ is odd}\}$$ is also true.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, "for any" means "for all" means $\forall$. "Any" implies you pick an arbitrary integer, so it must be true for all of them.

As for mods: usually, it's not expressed as an operator, but instead as a kind of equivalence relation: $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$ means that $n$ divides $a - b$. So you would write "m is odd" as $m \equiv 1 \pmod 2$.

Comment: In fact there **is** a binary mod operation: $x\bmod y$ is defined to be $x-y\lfloor x/y\rfloor$ for $y\ne 0$. The $\LaTeX$ code for it is `\bmod`. It is perfectly correct to write $m\bmod 2=1$ for ‘$m$ is odd’.

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, do mathematics persons generally recognize `%` as the modulo operator? It doesn't take much to change my `m%2=1` to `m=1 (mod 2)`, but I'd rather remain consistent.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott That is true, but I think it's correct to say the usual expression is a relation? And @ riista, no, I'd bet most would know what you're talking about, but it's not considered correct, as far as I know.

Comment: @riista: In my view the only thing that makes it look odd to a mathematician is the use of % instead of $\bmod$.

Comment: @Henry: *Usual* seems to me a bit too strong; the binary operation is increasingly common, and in this context it’s more convenient.

Comment: Cheers, you've both been immensely helpful. I would have thought there'd be some consistency between mathematics and compsci, so I was confused by % is not the universal operator. However, upon further recollection, a lot of languages also use `mod` in place of a % so it makes sense. Thanks again.

Comment: "any" can also mean "there exists"; it depends on the particular sentence.

Comment: But "for any" is unambiguously "for all".

Answer (score 2):

If a statement is true "for all", it implies that it is true for a subset or in this case for any one element.