# Converting statements with term 'only' and 'any' to predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

How to convert following statement into predicate logic?

```
1)"Only dogs are mammals"
2)"Any dog is a mammal"
```

Is there a difference between "Any dog is a mammal" and "All dogs are mammals" fro the view point of first order logic?

Comment: "Only dogs are mammals" becomes "every mammal is a dog."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is claiming that of all possible things or creatures, only dogs are mammals (I.e., anything other than a dog is not a mammal. I.e. all mammals are dogs.)

---

The second is indeed equivalent to "All dogs are mammals": i.e. "Considering all creatures, if  any of them is a dog, then it is a mammal."

The second (unlike the first) does NOT rule out the fact that there may be non-dog creatures that are also mammals.

Comment: So here are my answers. Am I correct?                            1)∀x (mammmal(x) -> dog(x) )                                     2)∀x (dog(x) -> mammal(x) )

Comment: Yes, that's correct!

Comment: One has to be careful with "any". In ordinary mathematical English, it can sometimes mean "some" and sometimes mean "all". See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/509828/630 and the comments below it for some examples.

Comment: E.g. "My plan will handle animals in the zoo that are not striped. So if no animal in the zoo is striped, I am fine. But if any animal in the zoo is striped, my plan will fail." - in this sentence, "any animal in the zoo" is an existential quantifier, not a universal quantifier.

Comment: Good points, @CarlMummert. Thanks for pointing out the caution (and knowledge of context) needed when handling "any".

Comment: @CarlMummert U re correct. Thanks for ur comments.